# PostgreSQL BETWEEN selects record when not fulfilled

Tags: postgresql

Why does this query returns a record?:

```
db2=> select * FROM series WHERE start <= '882001010000' AND "end" >= '882001010000' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
  id   |      timestamp      |  start   |   end    |
-------+---------------------+----------+-----------
 23443 | 2016-12-23 17:10:05 | 88160000 | 88209999 |
```

or with BETWEEN:

```
db2=> select * FROM series WHERE '882001010000' BETWEEN start AND "end" ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
  id   |      timestamp      |  start   |   end    |
-------+---------------------+----------+-----------
 23443 | 2016-12-23 17:10:05 | 88160000 | 88209999 |
```

start and end are TEXT columns.

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing numbers as `text`? Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are returning records because you are doing the comparisons as *strings* not as numbers.

Hence:  `'8'` is between `'7000000'` and `'9000'`, because the comparisons are one character at a time.

If you want numeric comparisons, you can cast the values to numbers.  Or, better yet, represent the values as numerics.  Postgres has the nice capability of very large precisions.